# PHP MySQL Is there any way to get the column key from an error

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

I'm creating a signup system for a website. The MySQL database has unique fields so users can not make more than one account on the same email, username or phone number. When data is duplicated an error comes back using mysqli_error() e.g. Duplicate entry 'email@example.com' for key 'EMAIL', this has the error code 1062. What I want to do is to then send the user back to input a different email address, username or phone number and to do this I need the KEY for the column in this case 'EMAIL' is there any way to do this from the error send back.
Thank-you

Comment: Do not use deprecated fuctions.

Comment: Remove the `mysqli_error()` function (My tip: only use this for debugging only, not in public. This messages let possible attackers know your system is vulnerable.). This error caused by using `email` as a **primary key**..

Comment: "select *" absolutely drives me crazy.  Never use it.  It's lazy and causes issues - in addition to returning a lot more data than is needed, particularly in wide tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the check query before inserting like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE email = '$email' OR phone = '$phone' OR username = '$username'
```

Then you can make simple check and throw exception/error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add validation rules: check email, phone and username on uniqueness before save to database.

```
select * from users where email = ?
select * from users where phone = ?
```

Than if row exists - write message to user. Otherwise create new row.

Also you should have UNIQUE indexes on phone and username. It is necessary if you have a big table (100k+ rows) to avoid slow inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

You should add validation rules: check **email**, **phone** and **username** on uniqueness before save to database.

```
select * from users where email = ?
select * from users where phone = ?
```

Than if row exists - write message to user. Otherwise create new row.

Also you should have UNIQUE indexes on phone and username. It is necessary if you have a big table (100k+ rows) to avoid slow inquiries.